# perform function once element loaded - angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to have an angular function fire after an element has displayed on the page.

The element is part of a SPA where what is displayed is controlled by a whole bunch of events (so doing things on page load won't work). The display of this element's parent (and therefore the element itself) is controlled by an ng-if which calls a separate function. As the parent doesn't display until that function has returned, there's no logical place to include the logic to alter this child element within that function, and since it's called by angular because of the ng-if, there's no parent function to place the code in once the previous function has returned.

I am currently achieving this by putting the function with my logic in it that always returns true within an ng-if on a child element of the element that has the proper, useful ng-if on it, as this will run as soon as the element has the option of being displayed.  While **this does work**, I feel it's a very dodgy solution to the problem.  **Is there a more "proper" method of achieving this?**

Snippet of the HTML (function names changed for the sake of the question):

```
<div data-ng-if="shouldTheButtonDisplay()">
    <a class="btn"
       data-ng-click="irrelevantToQuestion()"
       data-ng-if="functionToPerformOnceElementLoaded()"
       href="#">
        button text
    </a>
</div>
```

Snippet of JS (details changed because irrelevant to question):

```
$scope.shouldTheButtonDisplay() {
    return booleanThatIsRelevantInContext;
}

$scope.functionToPerformOnceElementLoaded = function() {
    // Edit state of button (technically an anchor)
    var firstRowButton = document.querySelector("a.btn");
    firstRowButton.style.background = "green";

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try using `ng-init` instead of `ng-if` for *functionToPerformOnceElementLoaded* function.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done so:

```js
angular
  .module('yourModuleName', [])
  .controller('yourControllerName', yourControllerNameCtrl)
  .directive('yourDirectiveName', yourDirectiveNameDirective);


yourControllerNameCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function yourControllerNameCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.message = 'In controller';
  
    $scope.irrelevantToQuestion = function() {};
}


function yourDirectiveNameDirective()
{
    function doSomethingElse(scope)
    {
        scope.message = 'In directive';
    }
  
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: 'falsy',
        link: function(scope, element)
        {
            element.find('a').addClass('green');
          
            doSomethingElse(scope);
        }
    };
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="yourModuleName">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="yourControllerName">
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
    
    <div your-directive-name>
      <a class="btn"
         data-ng-click="irrelevantToQuestion()"
         href="#">
        button text
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would I still need to put ng-if="shouldTheButtonDisplay() " on the outer div of the button for this to work, or is there some other part of the directive that controls this?  If so, will the contents of the directive fire immediately after the button reveals itself, and only that first time (the green background was just an example) or would it either a) need more prompting or b) call the function whenever there's any change in scope?

Comment: `link`-function is called only once, but every time when its underlying element (here is `<div>`-element with its inner html) appears in the DOM. If you add the `ng-if="expression"` to the same `<div/>`-element - `link`-function will be called every time when `expression == true`